# X forward - Maximize toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, x11, putty, maximize-window

I have a GUI, that I need to run on Windows from a Linux machine. A top level window is created, and I would like to maximize this window, keeping the menu bar.

```
mytop = Toplevel()
mytop.wm_attributes("-zoomed", "1")
```

The above snippet works perfectly in Linux, but does not work when X-forwarding through Putty. I've found other commands, that are said to work for windows but they don't work either, and I suspect it has something to do with forwarding the GUI.

Thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: try ```-fullscreen``` which i think is right

Comment: I have just run your code and the answer is actually essentially in the callback ```_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"```

Comment: mytop.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True) does not work either. I get a tiny little window with the title. I forgot to mention in the OP, that in the toplevel is a scrolledtext box that seems to be created anymore, scrolledtext is packed with expand=True

Comment: mytop.wm_attributes("-fullscreen", True) does work when running from IDLE on Windows, but not through X-forward.